# Why isn't PhpStorm starting anymore?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I try to start PhpStorm the little Windows 10 loading circle pops up for like one second. After that disappears just nothing happens. I get no error message or error log. PyCharm and IntelliJ is working fine.

Any ideas or experience?

Comment: IDE version? Check `idea.log` for possible errors. On Windows that would typically be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2021.3\log`. If you are using JetBrains Toolbox App to install your IDEs then the path will be different. But you should be able to access it under the cog icon for that app in Toolbox. Or you can always search for `idea.log` files system wide. **P.S.** In case if PhpStorm hanged out -- double check that it's not there in the memory. If found there -- kill it.

Comment: just contact us via Help | Contact Support - we'll be able to assist you more constructively. There's a lot of stuff that could affect IDE startup: it's basically too much to list here.

Comment: I've found the error. I closed phpstorm and my backend services were still running in background. I've looked in my taskmanager under the point "details" and had to close it.